# Volcano plots: How is the data fitted?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, catalysis

When studying about catalysts I normally come accross volcano plots like the one shown below:
[image]

What confuses me is how are the two lines fitted, how do you determine what points to include and what points not to include. For example I could have included the two points for Pt and Ir to obtain a slightly different shape of the volcano plot. Is there a guidline for this?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious approach for me would be to find a partition of the set of points into two subsets and two straight lines, one for each subset, such that the sum of the squared residuals over both partitions is minimized.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but if it is not explicitly mentioned in the paper how the fitting is obtained, it is very likely 'drawn' as a visual guide instead of obtained through a rigorous statistical fitting. The use of 'descriptors' to create volcano plots is a somewhat inexact art, and the inherent errors in the computational method/approximations probably make a rigorous fitting irrelevant, besides a *very* general positioning of the peak.